# Overriding parent model loading in nested Ember.js route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm learning Ember and trying to figure how to do a signup form.

I have a `/users` route from before and I have created a `users/new` route. In my users route I load all the users from the store - and now my `users/new` route will load all the users - which is not really needed.

**Should I create a separate `users/index.js` route for the index or is there another way to override the parent model loading that I should be using?**

```
// app/router.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });

  this.route('users', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});

export default Router;
```

---

```
// routes/users.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('user');
  }
});
```

---

```
// routes/users/new.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.createRecord('user');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need `users` collection in the `users` children routes, it is reasonable to create `users.index` route and use `users` collection as model in `users.index` route only. In this case you could remove `users` route and controller files.